# How to use html inside jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a set of these buttons.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/839MH.png

On clicking the 4th bolt i want to call a select menu option like this.

My desired result is this on clicking the button is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6XIj.jpg

I want to know how to embed this html code in jquery or java script so that i can call it by onclick/click function. Below is my jquery code and html for the button.

Html code for my button

```
<img id="analysis" class="normal_button" src="buttons/analysis.png">
```

jquery code for button

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#analysis").click(function(){
alert("hello world");
});
});
```

Comment: you can create a new element in jquery by simply passing it the html: 
`var el = jQuery('<div>this is  a new new element</div>'); jQuery('#analysis').append(el)`

Comment: sorry the image link for the buttons is this one. I apologize for the bad link
imgur.com/uQDjbAf

Comment: @WardD.S. can you please show me a demo i am new to javascript and jquery

Comment: I would go with sahil's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31802638/1969960, simply create the box beforehand and give it `display: none` in css. When your button is clicked simply give it `display: block`, his jsfiddle illustrates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#analysis").click(function(){
     var eles = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>';
     $('#domchange').append(eles);
   });
});
<div id="domchange"></div>
```

`append` is used to insert. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9uf4ext/)

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/ refer this too fyi.

Comment: i used it but it creates multiple options means every time i click the button. i just want it to come once.

Comment: Then you have to use a flag to keep it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` for this rather than embedding html in `Jquery`.

Please refer https://jsfiddle.net/qen76fep/1/

**Explanation**:
You can use `display` property in `css` by first setting the `display` property of the `select` box to `none` and then on `click` on the `button` you can use the `display` property to '`block`'.

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

To have `toggling` effect on button click you can use `toggle()` function in `Jquery`.

Example: `jQuery('.selectbox').toggle();`

For reference: "http://api.jquery.com/toggle/"

Comment: @sameera i tried your method but it dosen't show me the options. I also tried to look for erroe in console no error displayed there too.